# Не постоянная ошибка компиляции из-за отсутствующего файла *.dll.config

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, компиляция, msbuild

Помогите понять в каком направлении искать решение проблемы.

Мне достался проект в который нужно установить nuget пакет *Microsoft.CodeAnalysis*. После установки в проектах типа Class library появился файл App.config и все компилируется. Однако если часто делать Rebuild Solution, то в какой то момент, т.е. не всегда, компиляция одного из проектов провалица с ошибкой "Could not copy the file "*C:[SolutionPath]\x64\Debug\[AssemblyName].dll.config" because it was not found*"

Т.е. Библиотека А зависит от библиотеки Б. И в какойто момет невозможно собрать проект А так как он не нашел файл проекта Б, а именно Б.dll.config.

Я пытался воключить деталезированный лог компиляции(build log verbosity), но при настройках лога в режиме Detailed и Diagnostic ошибка не появляется. Удалось поймать ошибку на уровне Normal. И всё что я там увидел это то, что проект Б действительно создает файл *.dll.config и собирается он раньше проекта А, но ошибка все равно происходит.

Есть у кого как искать причину или что может помочь в исправлении ситуации?
Я пытался удалить файл App.config у проекта Б, проект компилируется, но проблема не пропала.

Стек:
Visual Studio 2017 v15.9.14;
.Net framework 4.7.2;
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis v2.8.2